# New to java. How to add the item to specific repositories using a text file

Tags: java

My main class

```
int n, p;
    String d;
    manager m = new manager();

    Scanner f = new Scanner(i.class.getResourceAsStream("product.txt"));
    while (f.hasNextLine()) {         
        String[] s = f.nextLine().split(",");
        n = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        d = s[1];
        p = Integer.parseInt(s[2]);

        Item item = new Item(itemNo, description, price);
        m.addItems(item);

        if (s[3].contains("1")) {
            m.addRep(1, item);
        }
        if (s[3].contains("2")) {
            m.addRep(2, item);
        }
        if (s[3].contains("3")) {
            m.addRep(3, item);
        }

    }
}
```

Example from my text File:

34,table,1200,12

14,sofa,2950,123

format of s[3] is e.g. "12" and "123" to represent that item is in repositories with ID's 1, 2 and 3

Error I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:643)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:455)
at dadsaassi.manager.addRep(manager.java:26)
```

Java Result: 1
My Item class

```
public int itemNum = 0;
public String des = "";
public int price = 0;

public Item(int i, String d, int p) {
    itemNum = i;
    des = d;
    price = p;
}
```

My manager class

```
private ArrayList<Item> rep = new ArrayList<Item>();
private ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();   //creates ArrayList

public void addItems(Item item) { 
    list.add(item);
}

public void addRep(int num, Item item) {
    rep.add(num, item);
```

Comment: Post `dadsaassi.manager.java` code also

Comment: @ Karthikeyan Vaithilingam I have it the manager class in the main thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List` is 0 index based. At `manager.java`, whenever you try to add at 1 index of `rep` ArrayList than `rep.size()>0` is `true`.

```
 m.addItemToRepository(1, item);
```

So, it throws IndexOutOfBoundsException. Look at docs of [List.add(element, index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) method.

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index > size())

The solution is, you should not mention index at `rep` List

```
 m.addItemToRepository(item); //It will start from 0
```

or,

```
m.addItemToRepository(0, item);// Although index is here redundant.
```

**Edit:** If you need repository number, you can also use `Map<Integer, Item>`, where `Integer` is the repository number.

```
Map<Integer, Item> rep = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();

public void addItemToRepository(int num, Item item) {
  rep.put(num, item);
}
```

Comment: @ Masud I just recently started programming, so my knowledge in coding is fairly basic. Requirement of the program is to divided item into three repositories, which item will go to which  repositories depends on what number "123"  1 begin the 1st  repository and so on. Here is a example of item from my text file  "34,table,1200,12" (so this item goes on 1st  repository and 2nd  repository)

Comment: @MeroRai, Better you should use Map<Integer, Item> instead of List for repository.

Comment: @MeroRay If you want to stick with adding items to the arrayList with the index, which Masud said wouldn´t be the most safe way to go, then you should add a safety routine before adding them. You could check if `num > rep.size()` and if it´s the case add the item at `rep.size()`. But this wouldn´t be the most smooth way to go. Just try to leave out the index position when adding the item. 

Or as Masud proposed, use a HashMap, since you can add your items into the map by a key

Comment: @ Masud I am really sorry but could you show me how to implement it.

Comment: @ Masud how do I implement (display) it on main java class?